# Multiple Sequence in SQL Oracle / Varchar2 ID with letters and digits

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I am trying to 'generate' a Varchar ID that contains letters and digits too with a sequence, but I think there will be more sequences than one.

What I am looking forward to is something like this 'DJ_Digit_Digit_Letter_Letter_Letter'. An example would be DJ00WVX/DJ01HYZ/DJ99ZZZ. This is also my primary key so it would be good if I could not encounter any primary key errors.

I thought about working in ascii so I will generate numbers between 65 and 90 (A-Z) and Insert them into the column. Same for the numbers in ascii 45 to 57 or something like that. I don't know how I could use more sequences on the same column like 'letter_seq.nextvalue,digit_seq.nextvalue', i know that this example is wrong, but it was easier for me to explain it. Maybe all my thinking is wrong

In conclusion I need to get something that starts with DJ followed by 2 digits and 3 letters, all wrapped up in a primary key. It's ok to get like 20-30 unique entries, I think.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like this:

```
SQL> create table test (id varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq1;

Sequence created.

SQL> insert into test (id)
  2  with
  3  a as (select chr(64 + level) la from dual
  4        connect by level <= 26),
  5  b as (select chr(64 + level) lb from dual
  6        connect by level <= 26),
  7  c as (select chr(64 + level) lc from dual
  8        connect by level <= 26)
  9  select 'DJ' || lpad(seq1.nextval, 2, '0')
 10              || la || lb || lc id
 11  from a cross join b cross join c;

17576 rows created.

SQL>
```

Several sample values:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select id,
  3      row_number() Over (order by id) rna,
  4      row_Number() over (order by id desc) rnd
  5     from test
  6    )
  7  select id
  8  from temp
  9  where rna <= 5
 10     or rnd <= 5
 11  order by id;

ID
----------
DJ01AAA
DJ02AAB
DJ03AAC
DJ04AAD
DJ05AAE
DJ99OUK
DJ99OUL
DJ99OUM
DJ99OUN
DJ99OUO

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

However, if

> It's ok to get like 20-30 unique entries, I think.

means that you need to generate at most 30 values, well, you'd easily create them manually; why would you develop any software solution for that? If you started typing, you'd be over by now.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time and solution! I thought about 20-30  because I didn't know about how this is going to work haha. I was just wondering how can I manage to do this. In my country DJ00WXC is a valid license plate where DJ is the county name. I have a project where I am keeping a Car Database with their owners and other things and I was told that I need to generate the Primary key (ID) with a sequence.  As you can see, I am a beginner in SQL, how can I insert only 20 of this or a given number of IDs? How can I reduce the generated ID's? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to insert e.g. 20 rows, add line #12 (in my first query, INSERT):  `where rownum <= 20`.

Comment: Why would you use the license plate # as a unique identifier of a give auto?  The global industry standard for unique identification of a vehicle is VIN (Vehicle Identification Number), which is assigned to the vehicle at the manufacturing plant.  A given vehicle can have multiple license plates during its lifetime.

Comment: Thank you for asking. I need it to be unique because two cars in my country cannot have the same license plate and I am supposed to have it as a primary key. If you want to change it, you will go to a police station or something like that and delete your record on that license plate and get another or maybe not if you are not using the car anymore. I can do it on my database too by deleting the records.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `INVISIBLE` `IDENTITY` column and then create your letter-digit-letter sequence as a function generated from the invisible column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id_seq_value INT
               INVISIBLE
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY( START WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 175799 )
               NOT NULL
               CONSTRAINT table_name__id_seq_value__u UNIQUE,
  id           VARCHAR2(7)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                 CAST(
                   'DJ'
                   || TO_CHAR( FLOOR( id_seq_value / POWER( 26, 3 ) ), 'FM00' )
                   || CHR( 65 + MOD( FLOOR( id_seq_value / POWER(26, 2) ), 26 ) )
                   || CHR( 65 + MOD( FLOOR( id_seq_value / POWER(26, 1) ), 26 ) )
                   || CHR( 65 + MOD( id_seq_value, 26 ) )
                   AS VARCHAR2(7)
                 )
               )
               CONSTRAINT table_name__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name         VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

Then you can do:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( name ) VALUES ( 'Item1' );
INSERT INTO table_name ( name ) VALUES ( 'Item2' );
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID      | NAME 
> :------ | :----
> DJ00AAA | Item1
> DJ00AAB | Item2
> ```

*(If you want to increment the digits and the letters together then change the `IDENTITY` to `INCREMENT BY 17577` (26<sup>3</sup>+1).)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d419b957437946b91d3e1df5f4df6230)*